# Show that a solenoidal field is always a curl of a vector field

Tags: electromagnetism, differential-geometry, vector-fields

Can someone prove that:

$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{B} = 0 \implies \mathbf{B} = \nabla \times \mathbf{A}~?$$

I know that $$\nabla \cdot (\nabla \times \mathbf{A}) = 0$$ identically.

But can one prove that if $\mathbf{B} \neq \nabla \times \mathbf{A}$ for any $\mathbf{A}$ then, $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{B} \neq 0?$

Comment: Relativistically covariant formulation: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/113626/2451 . Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/92200/2451

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called Helmholtz theorem, which states that for any vector field $\vec{F}$ that is twice continuously differentiable in a bounded domain, we can perform the decomposition
$$
\vec{F} = - \vec{\nabla} \Phi + \vec{\nabla}\times\vec{A}
$$
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition for a derivation